# JUnit Testing if an object is in an arraylist

Tags: java, class, testing, arraylist, junit

Hey guys just started using JUnit I have a pet and owner class and in the owner class I am currently trying to write a test for for finding a certain Pet, and to use a remove methode remove a Pet and test to see that that pet has gone. I have an method in owner called find pet which takes in an id cycles through all the pets in the ArrayList and prints out the pet with the matching id

```
public int findPet(String petId)
    {
        int pos = -1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < pets.size() && pos == -1)
        {
            if (pets.get(i).getPetId().equalsIgnoreCase(petId))
            {
                pos = i;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

Heres what I have so far:

```
@Test
    public void testFindPet() {
        
        System.out.println("Testing the FindPet() method");
        Owner o1 = new Owner("OID57","John"); 
        o1.addPet("PID01","dog","bowwow",4); 
        o1.addPet("PID02","dog","shep",6); 
        o1.addPet("PID03","cat","meow",4); 
        o1.addPet("PID04","snake","wally",2);
        
        o1.removePet("PID01");
   
    }
```

So would anyone be able to help me find out how to write a test for finding a pet?

Comment: Help you how? You have the `findPet` method, what did you want to test? Whether it returns the right pos?

Comment: I want to test that the method actually finds Pet, i know I could just write code so i know it works but Im doing a couple of exercises on JUnit and want to know how to test it in JUnit

Answer (score 1):

Your test is trying to remove a pet but presumably should be exercising the `findPet` method.  Assuming that's the case something like this using JUnit assertions:

```java
@Test
public void testFindPet() {
    // Create an owner and some pets
    Owner owner = new Owner("OID57","John"); 
    owner.addPet("PID01","dog","bowwow",4); 
    owner.addPet("PID02","dog","shep",6); 
    owner.addPet("PID03","cat","meow",4); 
    owner.addPet("PID04","snake","wally",2);

    // Find a pet for this owner
    assertEquals(0, owner.findPet("P1D01"));

    // Check unknown pet
    assertEquals(-1, owner.findPet("unknown"));
}
```

(Also assumes the `findPet` method is a member of the owner class).

You might also want to look into using `@BeforeEach` to create an owner and pets that can be used across multiple test methods.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this

```
Owner owner;

@Before
public void setup() {
   owner = new Owner();
   //add pets to owner so that you dont have to do this in every test
   owner.addPet("PID01","dog","bowwow",4); 
   owner.addPet("PID02","dog","shep",6); 
   owner.addPet("PID03","cat","meow",4); 
   owner.addPet("PID04","snake","wally",2);
}

@Test
public void testFindPet() {
   int result = owner.findPet("PID04");
   owner.removePet("PID04");
   //checks if it removed certain pet
   assertNotEquals(result, owner.findPet("PID04"));
}
```

Comment: I think you are testing both findPet and removePet